# FFmpeg 6.0 won't work because the header files can't connect or interact with each other. How do I fix the files?

Tags: c++, winapi, ffmpeg

I am creating a win32 API C++ application with Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 in a .sln file. I've got quite far in basic functionalities & decided to try out video decoding & playing; I've practiced this before but not with C++. So, I looked to see good libraries & found FFmpeg. Of course, I thought this would be quite straightforward - just import the headers & code, right? No. Firstly, the FFmpeg I'm using is one of the pre-built binaries. The 'ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl-shared.zip' From the BtbN Github repository. I decompressed it with WinRar & placed the files in Program Files (x86). Later on, I realised my mistake of placing it with 32-bit programs since it's a 64-bit build. So I transferred it to Program Files. Even after this though my issue persists. The issue being that the .h files of FFmpeg cannot communicate with each other. For some reason, they can't navigate to where the header files are. I am quite sure the reason for this may have something to do with where I save the files, the directory. Nowhere on the FFmpeg website can I see where you're expected to have the file directory at. I am sure there's a preset file path that is expected. Maybe I've named the FFmpeg folder incorrectly? Or maybe it's not meant to go in Program Files? The current directory for the FFmpeg folder for me is: C:\Program Files\FFmpeg. Below I will provide pictures of the errors I get where the code can't connect to other .h files as well as the file path. I'll also provide my code.

```
#include <Windows.h> //imports the main win32 API library
#include <tchar.h> //imports macros for handling Unicode & ASCII char sets
#include <CommCtrl.h> //defines the common control classes
#include <stdio.h> //imports the standard C library
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <Richedit.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
#include <C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\include\\libavformat\\avformat.h>
#include <C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\include\\libavutil\\imgutils.h>
#include <C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\include\\libswscale\\swscale.h>
#include <C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\include\\libavutil\\avassert.h>
}

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib") //tells the linker to include Comctl32.lib in the .exe
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\lib\\avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\lib\\avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\lib\\avutil.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\lib\\swscale.lib")

#define EDIT_CONTROL 1
#define OPEN_FILE_BTN 2
#define SAVE_FILE_BTN 3
#define EMBOLDEN_BTN 4
#define ITALICISE_BTN 5
#define SCROLL_CONTAINER 6
#define FILEMENU_OPEN_FILE_BTN 7
#define ADD_ROW_BTN 8
#define CELL_1_ID 9
#define CELL_2_ID 10
#define CELL_3_ID 11
#define SCROLL_CONTAINER_TBL 12
// 946 0759 0609 | 163 739

HINSTANCE g_hInstance;
HWND g_hWndMain, g_hWndTabs, openFileBtn, saveFileBtn, hOpenFileEdit, hScrollContainer, hEditControl, tabHandle, emboldenBtn, italiciseBtn, FilemenuOpenFileBtn, tableContainer, tblHeaderOne,
tblHeaderTwo, tblHeaderThree, addRowBtn, hAddRowDialogue, hWnd, hWndCell1Label, hWndCell1Edit, hWndCell2Label, hWndCell2Edit, hWndCell3Label, hWndCell3Edit, hWndOkButton, hWndCancelButton, hRow, hCell1, hCell2, hCell3,
hWMP, OpenMp4Btn, hWMPContainer, hPlayBtn;
HMENU  hMenu, hSubMenu;
bool isBold = false, isItalic = false;


const int startX = 0;
const int startY = 60;
const int ROW_HEIGHT = 20;
const int CELL_WIDTH = 110;
static int numRows = 1;
static int numCols = 3;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcessMessages(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
INT_PTR CALLBACK AddRowDlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE currentInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE previousInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR cmdLine,
    _In_ int cmdCount)
{
    const wchar_t* CLASS_NAME = L"Windows App";
    WNDCLASS wc{};
    wc.hInstance = currentInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcessMessages;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    g_hWndMain = CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, L"Windows App",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        800, 600,
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    if (g_hWndMain == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Initialize common controls
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    // Create tab control
    g_hWndTabs = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, L"",
        WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE | TCS_SINGLELINE,
        0, 0, 800, 600,
        g_hWndMain, nullptr, currentInstance, nullptr);

    if (g_hWndTabs == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Add tabs to tab control, seperate tab later
    TCITEM tcitem;
    tcitem.mask = TCIF_TEXT;

    wchar_t buf1[] = L"Table View";
    tcitem.pszText = buf1;
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(g_hWndTabs, 0, &tcitem);

    wchar_t buf2[] = L"Text Files";
    tcitem.pszText = buf2;
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(g_hWndTabs, 1, &tcitem);

    wchar_t buf3[] = L"mp4 Files";
    tcitem.pszText = buf3;
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(g_hWndTabs, 2, &tcitem);



    //original location of button intitialisation


    ShowWindow(g_hWndMain, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(g_hWndMain);

    MSG msg{};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I severely doubt my code has anything to do with the issue though. It's probably directory-based. I just placed wWinmain here to keep with the character limit.

[image: The .h files can't find each other]
[image: The file path for the FFmpeg files]

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the header files (although Program Files is a pretty poor choice). What matters is that you **tell your compiler where you have put them**. In Visual Studio this means editing the project settings and adding locations to 'Additional Include Directories'.

Comment: Also not this, `#include <C:\\Program Files\\FFmpeg\\include\\libavformat\\avformat.h>`, it should be `#include <avformat.h>` Tell the compiler where the header files are, that will solve all your header file problems.

Comment: I tried doing something similar to this ( though I never noticed a field called additional include directories ) In additional library directories, I tried adding the path to FFmpeg & then including the .h files & .lib files. Though for some reason, this seemed to cause the windows.h library not to get recognised even though it’s declared on the first line. Also, I still think there may e an error with the directory Ffmpeg is placed in or it’s file name, as Ffmpeg would have a specific directory location for it’s headers right? Also, where should I put FFmpeg, if not Program Files? @john

Comment: You add the directory containing the header files not the header file name. Not sure why that would give you problems with windows.h

Comment: Never mind, I added the wrong directory path & I was placing the path to the include folder in the additional library directories filed for the linker not the additional include directories under the C/C++ section